# Can VPN prevent ISP from tracking?

Tags: vpn, isp

1. Is VPN able to hide the traffic from the tracking and viewed by the ISP or even government units?
2. Is VPN able to bypass the ISP internet hotspot quota limit? How did ISP track/identify whether user is using hotspot/tethering? Any alternate way to bypass ISP hotspot quota limit?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Yes, IF your VPN gateway does not provide your data to said government/ISP and your connection is not compromised by other means.

2.) No. Quota limits work by counting bytes (amount of data). A VPN does in fact generate even more traffic that your regular connection so you may even achieve the opposite of what you are trying to do.